# Aviso nas rotas ReactJS

Tags: node.js, react

Tenho a seguinte configuração de rota personalizada

```
 <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <IntroducingLayoutRoute exact path="/" component={Main} />
                <IntroducingLayoutRoute path="/about" component={About} />
                <IntroducingLayoutRoute path="/register" component={Register}
```

IntroducingLayout

```
const IntroducingLayout = ({ children }) => (                         
    <>
        <Header />
        <Menu />
        
        {children}
        
        <Footer />
    </>
  );  
  
  const IntroducingLayoutRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {  
    return (  
      <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (  
        <IntroducingLayout>  
            <Component {...matchProps} />  
        </IntroducingLayout>  
      )} />  
    )  
  };
```

Agora toda vez que clico numa rota tenho esse aviso

No arquivo

> index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in a useEffect cleanup function.
> in Home (at introducing/index.js:31)

Tentei usar assim:

```
const mountedRef = useRef(true)

    const execute = useCallback(() => {
      setLoading(true)
      return asyncFunc()
        .then(res => {
          if (!mountedRef.current) return null
          setData(res)
          return res
        })
    }, [])
  
    useEffect(() => {
      return () => { 
        mountedRef.current = false
      }
    }, [])
```

Mas não foi

Comment: você tem rotas protegidas?

Comment: Sim, tenho, mas essas que eu quero acessar não estão protegidas

Comment: é que está estranho não é feita assim não na rota! IntroducingLayout

Comment: `IntroducingLayout` significa que essas rotas terão um layout específico

Comment: mais ele não é o componente de rotas! entendeu

Comment: IntroLayoutRoute ta na rota e nos outros dois código estão outros nomes? estranho não!

Comment: você tem referencia desse código da onde?

Comment: Sim. [Aqui](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multiple-layout-in-react-with-react-router-v4/) e [aqui](https://medium.com/@benkissi/creating-multiple-layouts-in-react-react-router-v5-cebde25ff6e6)

Comment: `IntroLayoutRoute` realmente foi erro meu na digitação